# What propability distribution could be fitted to a noisy sinus signal

Tags: signal-processing

i'm currently working on feature extraction from noisy (real world measurement) sinusoid measurements. I was thinking about fitting a propability distribution over my signals propability to use the fitting parameters as signal features for further use in clustering etc.

Unfortunately, i was not able to find a suitable propability distribution function structure. The propability distribution of a noisy sinusoid should look like a smooth "M".

i found this:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199215/probability-distribution-of-a-sine-wave

but to my understanding, this cannot be applied to a noisy sinus.

Best Regards and many thanks in advance

Comment: What do you know about your sinusoid?

Comment: the distribution looks something like this: https://postimg.cc/p9KSznWD

Comment: I understand nothing. Your Stats SE question is on the distribution of $Y := \sin (X)$ when $X$ is uniformly distributed.  How is that useful to you? I would speculate you have something like $$\sin (\omega_0 t) + \eta (t)$$ where $\eta$ is additive noise.